# Where does the IBM OmniFind Yahoo! search engine cache Domain-IP resolutions?

Tags: lucene

We are using Omnifind on Windows 2008 Server for site search, and after one website has migrated to another server - same domain, another IP (DNS update has been more than 24 hours ago, Omnifind server knows new IP) -, Omnifind keeps searching the old IP, meaning it has cached the name resolution somewhere.

But where?

Omnifind uses Apache Lucene technology, so maybe someone has an idea about that one which might serve as a hint?

Restarting the service or the server doesn't change that behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer, and we haven't found out.

However, a workaround is to block access to the "old" IP, the apparently Omnifind will do another DNS check and find the new IP while keeping the index (we didn't do this in the first place because we were afraid that Omnifind might decide to delete the index).